# How to efficiently limit processes generated by SimPy in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, simulation, simpy

I'm trying to use SimPy to create a simulator which models the time it takes for a gas station to run out of capacity. It is a simulator which generates a car and then waits in a queue for a fuel pump to become available.

Because I'm not necessarily interested in how long it takes each individual car to access fuel but rather how long it takes under different demand scenarios for the station to run out of fuel, I'd like to limit my simulation such that it doesn't create cars unless a pump becomes available.

I'm not sure how to make the Resource class communicate availability to the car generator, so I currently just generate cars on a fixed interval, but I check the queue length to make sure it's not too long before the car yields a request to the Resource.

How do I make it such that the car generator only creates cars when the resource becomes available?

Here is my code so far:

```
import simpy
import random

def car(sim_env: simpy.Environment, station: simpy.Resource, pump: simpy.Container):
    # Checks queue, if it is long, don't create car
    if len(station.queue) < station.capacity + 5:
        # Creates random fuel needs for car, determine how much fuel is dispensed per unit of time
        fuel_needed = random.uniform(20, 30)
        fuel_rate = 10
        # Try to go to a fuel pump
        with station.request() as req:
            yield req
            # Get fuel available, if no fuel available, raise error
            if pump.level >= fuel_needed:
                yield pump.get(fuel_needed)
                car_time = (fuel_needed / fuel_rate)
                yield sim_env.timeout(car_time)
            elif fuel_needed > pump.level > 0:
                car_time = (pump.level / fuel_rate)
                yield pump.get(pump.level)
                yield sim_env.timeout(car_time)
            else:
                print('No fuel at station, exiting simulation')
                raise ValueError

def car_generator(sim_env: simpy.Environment, station: simpy.Resource, pump: simpy.Container,
                  generation_interval: tuple):
    low_interval = generation_interval[0]
    high_interval = generation_interval[1]
    while True:
        # Wait for car to arrive using car generation interval
        yield sim_env.timeout(random.uniform(low_interval, high_interval))
        sim_env.process(car(sim_env, station, pump))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create simulation environment
    env = simpy.Environment()
    # Create a station with 8 pumps
    gas_station = simpy.Resource(env, 8)
    # Specify the fuel capacity of the station to be 20000
    fuel_pump = simpy.Container(env, 20000, init=20000)
    env.process(
        car_generator(env, gas_station, fuel_pump, (1, 5)))
    # Run simulation
    try:
        env.run()
    except ValueError:
        print("Station out of gas")
```

Comment: Can the car generate the next car when when it finishes fueling?

You would still need to create your initial batch of cars at startup.  

Your other option is to rewrite the resource class

Answer (score 1):

I know that is not exactly what you asked, but what if you ignore the cars generated when there is no pump available?

If this is ok, a well placed "if gas_station.count() < 8:" will do the job.

Check the code bellow.

```
def car_generator(sim_env: simpy.Environment, station: simpy.Resource, pump: simpy.Container,
                  generation_interval: tuple):
    low_interval = generation_interval[0]
    high_interval = generation_interval[1]
    while True:
        # Wait for car to arrive using car generation interval
        if gas_station.count() < 8:
           yield sim_env.timeout(random.uniform(low_interval, high_interval))
           sim_env.process(car(sim_env, station, pump))
```